# IPSec nftables strongswan

Tags: ipsec, strongswan, debian-buster, nftables

How to configure nftables to allow inbound only ipsec traffic and process rules after decryption. I have nftable.conf:

```
#!/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

# ----- IPv4 -----
table ip filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        ct state invalid counter drop comment "early drop of invalid packets"
        ct state {established, related} counter accept comment "accept all connections related to connections made by us"
        iif lo accept comment "accept loopback"
        iif != lo ip daddr 127.0.0.1/8 counter drop comment "drop connections to loopback not coming from loopback"
        ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request counter accept comment "accept ICMP echo-request types"

        # Accept SSH incoming traffic
        tcp dport ssh counter accept comment "accept SSH"

        # Accept IPsec traffic
        udp dport { isakmp, ipsec-nat-t } counter accept comment "accept ISAKMP and IPsec NAT traversal"
        ip protocol { ah, esp } counter accept comment "accept AH and ESP"

        counter comment "count dropped packets"
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
        counter comment "count dropped packets"
    }

    # If you're not counting packets, this chain can be omitted.
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        counter comment "count accepted packets"
    }
}


# ----- IPv6 -----
table ip6 filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
        ct state invalid counter drop comment "early drop of invalid packets"
        ct state {established, related} counter accept comment "accept all connections related to connections made by us"
        iif lo accept comment "accept loopback"
        iif != lo ip6 daddr ::1/128 counter drop comment "drop connections to loopback not coming from loopback"
        counter comment "count dropped packets"
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
        counter comment "count dropped packets"
    }

    # If you're not counting packets, this chain can be omitted.
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        counter comment "count accepted packets"
    }
}
```

IPSec configured with StrongSwan, ping passing thru after adding rule:

```
ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request counter accept comment "accept ICMP echo-request types"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ESP decapsulation, firewall rules will be re-processed automatically – you don't need any special actions.

Use the following match condition in order to filter inbound packets that were secured:

- `meta ipsec exists` on latest versions (nft ≥0.9.1)
- `meta secpath exists` on older versions (Linux ≥4.15, nft ≥0.8.2)

For example,

```
tcp dport 3306 meta ipsec exists accept
tcp dport 3306 reject
```

Inverse:

```
meta ipsec missing drop
```

---

Also, don't create separate ip/ip6 filter tables – you're only duplicating the work you need to do. (For example, currently you forgot to allow SSH and ESP over IPv6...) Just put everything in one inet table – rules will automatically apply to the correct protocol when they filter by IP address, and to both protocols when they don't.

Comment: I will have different rules for ipv6 and ipv4 traffic, thats why I separated it. Thank U for help. That's what I need.